# How to change the default username a postgresql db is connecting to?

Tags: postgresql, default, psql

I've seen posts that describe how to set postgresql server to connect to your own user but I could not find any posts that describe how to make `psql` connect to the default `postgres` user instead by default. In my case, right after installation when I open up `psql`, it connects to the username with the name same as my windows user instead of the `postgres` user that I want it to connect to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-ENVIRONMENT) you can define an environment variable `PGUSER` which is used instead of your Windows user as the default user for all Postgres command line tools.

Comment: Is there a possibility to define an `environment` file within a certain directory to be used as default? I'm using iterm and asdf.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a psqlrc.conf file with following data:

```
\c <database> <user>
```

[Doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) says:

> The user's personal startup file is named .psqlrc and is sought in the
>   invoking user's home directory. On Windows, which lacks such a
>   concept, the personal startup file is named
>   %APPDATA%\postgresql\psqlrc.conf. The location of the user's startup
>   file can be set explicitly via the PSQLRC environment variable.